# Can I use Amazon EC2 from behind a proxy server?

Tags: r, proxy, amazon-ec2

I am using `EC2` from my laptop (`Ubuntu 12.04`) with `RStudio` running in a web browser all behind a proxy server.  I'm assuming `RStudio` is picking up the proxy settings from the web browser setup page.

I'd like to use a terminal window to do some other stuff on the `EC2` instance but can't figure out where to feed it the proxy settings.

Is it somewhere in the security groups area?  or can I just add something to the connection command in terminal (`ie ssh -i myKey12345.key user@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -user:pass:proxyIP:port` )?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just follow the steps in [common EC2 / Ubuntu tutorials like this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide) and your final steps often are the `ssh` command to actually take a shell on the EC2 instance.

If and when your local policies prevent the above from reaching the EC2 instance, you need to work your ssh setup accordingly.  In my experience, "ssh outbound" is often permissive.  Your mileage may differ, but in that case it is becoming an ssh configuration question.